# git reset --hard origin/master still giving different code

Tags: github, github-actions

hello guys i want to ask about my GITHUB problem, why is my local master branch is different from remote?, i was modifying without committing then git branch -b and git add and git commit, and then after i push the new branch, create pull request, and merged to master, its different when i comeback to local master and git pull

i also already do `git fetch origin` and `git reset --hard origin/master`
the code is almost the same as remote but its just weird, a few declaration is missing and one entity naming is the same as my other branch

Comment: Is the comparison being made between your local `master` and the remote `master` branch?  There should be no differences AFAIK.

Comment: yeah it turns out because theres unsaved tab from before when i was working with another branch, close that tab and unsaved it solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

it turns out, that there is open tab in VSCode that i havent saved from another branch, close it out and dont save it solved the problem